# PHP How to show results search google.com on site?

Tags: php

I would like show results find in google in frame.
find query

```
https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=test%20speed
```

i use code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=test%20speed" 
    width="100%" scrolling="auto">
</iframe>
```

but i get header:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=test%20speed' 
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

As we can see server google not get show site in frame.

Tell me please how show results find google.com on my site ?

Comment: Google doesn't allow you to do this. They offer a product for your needs, though, [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/).

Comment: @Carsten you are not know - curl or file_get_content wiil be work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use their API, not iframe.
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/ (custom search) or this: https://developers.google.com/web-search/?hl=ru
latest is better cause u can get an array with the results and print as you want, here my sample on php:

```
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
     . "q=" . urlencode($your_query) . "&userip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$jsonResult = file_get_contents($url);

$out = json_decode($jsonResult);
```

`$out` will contains array with the results, you can `foreach` them:

```
foreach ($out->responseData->results as $record)
{
    $this->_results['search'][] = array(                
        'title' => $record->title,
        'description' => $record->content,
        'sourceUrl' => $record->url,
        'sourceShortUrl' => $record->visibleUrl,            
    );   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `&output=embed` to the end of the `URL` before posting to the `Google`.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=test%20speed&output=embed" 
    width="100%" scrolling="auto">
</iframe>
```

Comment: i get error: `https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=test&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'`